# How to make the Wifi of Airport Extreme and Macbook go back to 802.11ac?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, airport

It was 99.99% of the time my Macbook and the Apple Airport Extreme were connected by 802.11ac, and today, nothing has changed, and they were shown to be connected by 802.11n all of a sudden, and it has been so for hours. (by pressing Option and clicking on the Wifi icon on the task bar).

How do I make it jump back to 802.11ac?

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply turning WiFi off and then on again from the WiFi icon in the top bar.

If it still doesn't work, you'll need to check if you've made settings changes on the router - or if some source of interference has been introduced to the environment (such as another WiFi access point, or other electronical equipment). If this is the case, you can sometimes work around it by changing the WiFi channel used on the Airport Extreme from its settings.

Comment: yeah... just wondering if that will break the current connections if some files are being copies or transferred

Comment: It depends on the type of connection used for transferring those files. Usually the reconnect happens so quickly that file copies are not affected, but it depends on how you're copying.